# How can I know what libs are being linked dynamically into a static lib?

Tags: c++, linker, libraries, loader

Say I have a libmy.a static library, and I want to know what libraries it links dynamically. Actually I need that for the following: I am gonna create a new dynamic lib say libmy2.so which will link say an .o file (object file) and the libmy.a. So I wonder what libs will load libmy2.so eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries do not link other libraries, either static or dynamic.

OK, assuming two C++ files, a.cpp and b.cpp.

```
g++ -c a.cpp -o a.o         // compile a.cpp to a.o
rm -f lib1.a                // no existing lib1.a (this is not essential)
ar rvs lib1.a a.o           // create library lib1.a and add a.o to it
g++ -c b.cpp -o b.o         // compile b.cpp to b.o
ar rvs lib1.a b.o           // ad b.o to existing lib1.a
```

You can obviously do any amount of copying between stages to produce the library with the name you want. You can also do

```
ar --help
```

to get the ar options which might simplify the process slightly. Frankly, it's a command I almost never use except to build static libraries from a list of objects.

Comment: Particularly, do you meen that I can't build a static lib, which links other libs statically?

Comment: @Narek Yes - the application or shared library can link with other static or shared libraries, but static libraries cannot, as they are simply archives of object files.

Comment: What is wrong to link to an object file a bunch of object files, i. e. a static lib, and get abunch of object file + 1 static lib?

Comment: @Narek  You can archive (not link) a bunch of object files to PRODUCE a static library.

Comment: Please write the command which will produce libb1.a from liba1.a by adding into it the myObject.o file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folllowing commands to check the contents of your static libraries:

```
nm -C libname.a | less
```

or

```
$ar -vt libname.a
```

Answer (score 0):

on a mac, it would be 
nm -m C libname.a

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic library will dynamically link only to those dynamic libraries which you specify with `-l` when building it. Static libraries are principally linking time entities representing a set of *.o files and they must be processed by linker to produce executable code so there is no requirement that all implementations must be provided when building a static library. All is set up during the final link of the target executable.